# CONCAT multiple fields which may have NULLS, set the delimiter once: SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, delimiter, concatenation, isnull

I would like to concatenate many columns in SQL Server 2008 R2, and have them delimited by a TAB. So far, I have only been able to come up with a primitive solution:

```
select 
   isnull(col1,'') 
   + CHAR(9) 
   + isnull(col2,'') 
   + CHAR(9) 
   + isnull(col3,'') 
   + CHAR(9) 
   + isnull(col4,'') 
   + CHAR(9) 
   + isnull(col5,'') 
from TBL_A
```

> For the sake of brevity, I only included 5 columns, however I need to concatenate about 20 columns.

Since any of the columns could be NULL, I need to wrap each columns in the `isnull` statement. I also need to add the `char(9)` after every column. CONCAT_WS would take care of both of these issues very simply however this is only available in SQL Server 2017.

Does anyone have a more eloquent way of doing this?

Comment: I'd use stuff with for xml path. [here is an example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125780/95107)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like a `STUFF()` in combination with `FOR XML PATH()` and an `UNPIVOT` should get this done for you. I don't think there's a way around the multiple null checks.

Here is a working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b0489/1) of how you might accomplish this.

```
-- schema
create table t1 (
    id int
    ,col1 char(1)
    ,col2 char(1)
    ,col3 char(1)
);

create table t2
(
    id int,
    colVal char(1)
);

-- some sample data
insert into t1
select 1, 'a', 'b', 'c'
union all
select 2, 'd', 'e', 'f';

insert into t2
select 
    id
    ,colVal
from t1
unpivot
(
    colVal
    for cols in (col1, col2, col3)
) u
order by
    id;

-- the actual query
select 
    id
    ,stuff((
        select
            '-'
            + isnull(colVal,'') 
        from
            t2 as innerTable
        where 
            innerTable.id = outerTable.id
        for xml path (''))
    ,1 , 1, '')
from
    t2 as outerTable
group by
    id;

drop table t1;
drop table t2;
```

The process here is as follows:

1. "Verticalize" the data using `UNPIVOT` and the row identifier to allow us to aggregate it back into row groups later on.
2. Use a [correlated subquery](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638(v=sql.105).aspx) to query against the vertical data **per group**.
3. Using `FOR XML PATH('')` to combine the record values into a delimited string and `STUFF` to chop off the leading separator.

> Note that I've used dashes in my example to make it clearer how the separators are coming into play. I also made the presumption that your records have some form of unique identifier (`id int` in the example).

Comment: Looks like there is a ',' missing before the '0'. Also, if I add the ',', I get a result of null.

Comment: @SRev I apologize for my initial misunderstanding/oversimplification of the problem. I've updated my answer to better serve the question at hand.